# last div will not collapse when using bootstrap collapse javascript

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following example of how I'm trying to use the bootstrape collapse javascript feature. 
http://jsfiddle.net/jsieber/xSf5a/4/

The 6th div stays open even though all other divs close when a different div is opened. i'm using the hosted bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.min.css files as resources. Is this a know bug in the bootstrap-collapse.js implentation, or do I have an error in my markup that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No bug, just an error in your markup: You forgot a closing `</div>` in the fifth accordion-group.  The selector for closing an collapsible element is

```
this.$parent.find('> .accordion-group > .in')
```

So it's not going to find the collapsible element if it's an accordion-group nested inside another accordion-group.

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/vZdrC/)